# What is the optimal solution: WP Multisite vs InfiniteWP

Tags: multisite

My requirements:
 - 100 websites
 - All same themes and plugins and layouts
 - Different categories/pages structures
 - All custom domains - not sub domain/directory

Priorities:
 - Efficiency in management
 - Performance
 - Plugin issues avoiding
 - Overly complicated future code development

In case you’re curious, these will be websites dedicated to local areas - so same websites with different content and maybe different structures if required

What is the optimal solution?

Comment: This is a hard question to answer, as performance tends to be more of a host-by-host basis. My personal opinion would lean toward using InfiniteWP and keeping them separate, simply because there are so many sites, and since their content is completely unique. Think about it this way: if your site got hacked, would you rather the hacker gain access to one of the sites (separate installs) or possibly all of the sites (multisite)? Unless you have a lot of users who will need access to multiple sites, MultiSite doesn't seem like a good fit here.

Comment: You'd need to  ask someone with InfiniteWP knowledge. Nothing in multisite prevents you from using arbitrary custom  domains for sites.